# Mirroring function to do the opposite

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I have this event to turn my music of by fading it out

```
    $(bgMusic).on('timeupdate', function () {
    var vol = 1,
        interval = 250;
    if (bgMusic.volume == 1) {
        var intervalID = setInterval(function () {
            if (vol > 0) {
                vol -= 0.05;
                bgMusic.volume = vol.toFixed(2);
            } else {
                clearInterval(intervalID);
            }
        }, interval);
    }
});
```

I now want the same thing for turning the music on.

I have tried creating the opposite like this:

```
    $(bgMusic).off('timeupdate', function () {
    var vol = 0,
        interval = 250;
    if (bgMusic.volume == 0) {
        var intervalID = setInterval(function () {
            if (vol < 0) {
                vol += 0.05;
                bgMusic.volume = vol.toFixed(2);
            } else {
                clearInterval(intervalID);
            }
        }, interval);
    }
});
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you change:

`if (vol < 0) {`

to:

`if (vol < 1) {`

... I think the volume should gradually increase until it meets it maximum value of 1, hence giving you the "fade in" effect you ask for.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your code but I think you don't want to use the off function in your second example.

[jQuery off:](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

> Description: Remove an event handler.

So try your second code with on to, since you want to register to the event, not remove it.

Comment: Well spotted Stefan, but I can't quite give you a +1 since you didn't mention the problem with the `if` condition...

Comment: What would you suggest? Go back to .on? @Stefan

Comment: Yes, you have to use on too. But you would need a second button, or since if you use the same, both applie and I can't really say what wiill happen. Otherwise you can remove the handler after it is completed (with the off function).

Comment: At the moment I have it fading out on the click of the start button and fading in on the click of the restart button. But it is stuck in some sort of loop and keeps going up and down without even triggering the events with a click. Do you know why this would happen? @Stefan

Answer (score 0):

since your vol is 0 , it doesnot goes inside the if condition..  `if (vol < 0) {...`
it should be

```
   if (vol < 1) {
            vol += 0.05;
            bgMusic.volume = vol.toFixed(2);
        } else {
            clearInterval(intervalID);
        }
```